# Xbap application -- WPF host has encountered a prob and needs to close

Tags: wpf, internet-explorer-8, xbap

I have developed a Xbap application and it has been deployed on customer site and it is working fine for all computers but one of them.
On this computer, when loading the application following error message appears:

[image]

The mentioned computer having following details:

- OS: Windows XP SP3 -
- .Net Framework 3.5
- IE 8

I have checked the Browser's setting and it is quite similar to other computers.
Any suggestions?

P.S. : My application needs to be set as PARTIAL TRUST, and as it is working fine on all other computers, so changing it to FULL TRUST is not an option here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be a registry permissions problem with Windows XP.  We started having this appear on a couple of computers in the last week.  Here’s a link to a fix from Microsoft:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=5766

Comment: Thanks Chris, 
Unfortunately at the time we did not find the solution and re-installed Windows on that machine and everything sounds working fine.